# Converting Post API response token into a object

Tags: android, ios, json, flutter, api

I have a project that is a simple sign up and login page. On successful login the API post a token back to the terminal. What I would like to do next is store this token as an object so I can use the token keep the user logged in in the future

[image: Codeimage]

I think in some way I need to save instances and preferences - if someone could give me an outline that to do so that would be great

Comment: Do not post code as an image. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use package to save the token on local storage.

- Shared Preferences https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences
- Flutter Secure Storage https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage

Example using flutter secure storage

```
await storage.write(key: token, value: tokenValue);
```